# How do I determine the location of each pixel in a square drawn via Core Graphics?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I am trying to get each pixel point of a Square drawn using Core graphics.Here by making the stroke color black color,I am drawing the Square.Please give me an idea how I will get all pixel point on which this square is drawn.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable(); 
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, 30.0f, 30.0f);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 130.0f, 30.0f);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 130.0f, 130.0f);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, 30.0f, 130.0f);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
    CGPathRetain(path);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor); 
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx,[UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0);
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, path); 

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
    CGPathRelease(path);
}
```

Comment: Is this a trick question? I'd say just off the top of my head that the points are (30,30), (130, 30), (130, 130) and (30, 130). Am I missing something? Please elaborate what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you doing all this work instead of just using `CGContextFillRect()` and `CGContextStrokeRect()`?

Your code above can be simplified to:

```
CGRect r = CGRectMake(30.0, 30.0, 100.0, 100.0);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, CGColorGetConstantColor(kCGColorClear));
CGContextFillRect(ctx, r);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, CGColorGetConstantColor(kCGColorBlack));
CGContextStrokeRect(ctx, r);
```

Also, ***never*** send `-setNeedsDisplay` within your `-drawRect:` method.  You'll get an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar for my iPhone app and while I realize it is a little late, I decided to respond anyway.

First, initialize a mutable array (points).

Next, find the minimum X and Y coordinates for your CGRect.
Do the same for the maximum.

Find the difference between the minimum and the maximum.

Now, create a for loop like the one below:

```
for(int x = minX; x<diffX+minX; x++){
    for(int y = minY; y<diffY+minY; y++){
        [points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(x,y)]];
    }
}
```

You can now access your points through the points array.